# How to define tablelayout dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, layout

How do I create table rows dynamically in this columns should be in horizontal way and each row should be separated by single line or different colours in Android.

Comment: The wording of your question is a little confusing, could you explain a little further what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the following code.
layout is table Layout;rowColor is the color you can set for the row background

```
TableRow tr1=new TableRow(this);
TextView title=new TextView(this);
title.setText(tit);
title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
tr1.addView(title,150,30);
tr1.setBackgroundColor(rowColor);
layout.addView(tr1);
```